# Problem with showing markdowns of Jupyter wrongly in pdf

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, markdown

When I save the jupyter notebook as pdf, the format of markdown cells totally change.

This is how it is shown in jupyter notebook
[jupyter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyX3u.png)

This is how it is shown in pdf:
[pdf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynW1Z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting to PDF, Jupyter first converts the notebook to LateX and then uses `pdflatex`. That's why a lot of the formatting is lost.

A workaround is to download the notebook as an HTML file, and then print/save the HTML file as PDF in a browser. This will conserve all the markdown.

Example result:
[image: using HTML to PDF]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I've done that. when converting HTML to pdf the same problem happens plus some code cells are lost!

Comment: Yes the HTML file is totally fine. I used the code "jupyter nbconvert --to html ..."

Comment: I mean, how did you convert the HTML to a PDF?

Comment: sorry, by: file->print->PDF also by export as pdf

Comment: I'm using safari. I'll try chrome now. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: In chrome also I had the same problem!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue unfortunately. As a last resort, maybe try converting the HTML file to PDF using a site like https://html2pdf.com/

Comment: Thank you so much.